# How to start an injected service before a call has been made to the API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core I have a service that prepare for injection in startup:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IService, Service>();
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

If I make a call to the API, it will start up.
However, I'd like it to initialize before hand (when the app starts).
I'm simply putting a breakpoint in the controller to see if that happens.

Comment: why you want to start your startup before calling??

Comment: Depending on what your `IService` does, this could be a very bad idea.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I'm prototyping a service bus receiving and I need to run it from the start. The reason it is in an API is so I can interact with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`AddSingleton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Type_System_Object_) method can take either a type or an object to give. So you can simply do:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var serviceInstance = new Service();
    serviceInstance.DoWhatever();
    services.AddSingleton<IService, serviceInstance>();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core apps use a Startup `class`, which is named `Startup` by convention. The `Startup` class:

- Can optionally include a ConfigureServices method to configure the app's services.
- Must include a Configure method to create the app's request processing pipeline.

`ConfigureServices` and `Configure` are called by the `runtime` when the app starts:

```
public class Startup
{
    // Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
    }

    // Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Specify the Startup class with the **WebHostBuilderExtensions** UseStartup method:

```
public class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
   }

   public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
      WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
          **.UseStartup<Startup>();**
}
```

So if you want to cal something at start the project in `Startup` put your method in `Confirgure`

GoodLuck.

Answer (score 0):

you could try placing your initialization logic in the constructor so you don't need to worry about calling the "proper method". this will also help you in the case when your service is dependent on another one in order to function properly. long live dependency injection :)